# Median-of-Medians algorithm, calculating the constant c

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding how the calculation of the constant $c$ in the Median-of-Medians-algorithm is build up ($cn$). The only [calculation I found was on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Analysis):

$$\frac{2g(g-1)}{g-3}$$

My question: Why is it exactly minus 1 or multiplied by 2 etc.? How did this term come together?

I do understand the other parts of the algorithm, but if we have, for example $n/7$ groups, then the constant $c$ should grow accordingly. Even though that doesn't matter in the calculation of the Big-O notation I would still like to understand it to help me understand the algorithm in it's entirety. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Wikipedia is, on average, a horrible resource for learning about (analysis of) algorithms. Get an algorithms textbook, you'll profit.

Comment: Note that you can use MathJax here, which is usually preferable over image-maths.

Comment: That Wikipedia article has a "References" section, and "External Links".  Have you tried looking at those?  If not, that's a good next step.  Wikipedia is not a primary reference; when you don't understand it, you should start by consulting primary references (e.g., textbooks; the sources that it cites).  Primary sources are more likely to have a careful derivation.